Is it possible to use the Azure CLI command `az aks get-credentials` without changing the current context for `kubectl`?
Is it possible to run an Azure CLI command like:
az aks get-credentials --overwrite-existing --name test-aks-cluster --resource-group test-resource-group

without changing the current context that kubectl will use?
Update: Although it is indeed possible to write the credentials to a different file. In this case, my prefered end goal would be to update the standard ${HOME}/.kube/config, while not changing the current context at all.
When running scripts, I often want to ensure that the credentials are current, but I don't want to change the context, since other things might be currently running. Instead, I will often just specify the --context argument on the kubectl command, but I would really prefer that az not mess around with the current context at all.

If you prefer not to use the --context option with kubectl, you can use the --file option with the az aks get-credentials command to store the the kubeconfig file to a specific location, and then use the KUBECONFIG environment variable to specify the location of the kubeconfig file when running kubectl commands.
az aks get-credentials --name test-aks-cluster --resource-group test-resource-group --file /path/kubeconfig

Apart from the --context option which you are already using. Something like this- az aks get-credentials --overwrite-existing --name test-aks-cluster --resource-group test-resource-group --context my-custom-context , in order to update the AKS credentials in the standard ${HOME}/.kube/config file without changing the current context, the best approach is to save the current context before updating the credentials and restore it afterward using a script.
#!/bin/bash


current_context=$(kubectl config current-context 2>/dev/null)
if [ -z "$current_context" ]; then
    echo "No current context is set. Please set a context before running this script."
    exit 1
fi


az aks get-credentials --overwrite-existing --name test-aks-cluster --resource-group test-resource-group


if [ -n "$current_context" ]; then
    kubectl config use-context $current_context
fi

echo "Updated AKS credentials without changing the current kubectl context."


Basically, the script saves the current context to a variable, updates the kubeconfig file with the new credentials then restores the original context that was saved before updating the credentials and finally prints a message confirming the update.
I think this approach can work as a workaround where the credentials for your AKS cluster are updated in the standard ${HOME}/.kube/config file without changing the current context used by kubectl.
References:

az aks get-credentials command documentation

